# I cannot re-size uploaded image in MVC - razor view

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Actually what I want is to display an image in a default uploaded image size.

This is the code in my View.

```
<div class="uploadBannerForCourse">
    <img class="absoluteDisplaysize" src="~/File?id=@Model.Files.First(f => f.FileType == SmartJob.Domain.Models.ProfessionCourseModels.FileType.Avatar).FileId" alt="avatar" height="" />
</div>
```

This is the CSS File.

```
.uploadBannerForCourse{
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    width:50px;
}

img.absoluteDisplaysize{
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -200px;
    position:absolute;
 }
```

Comment: What size is it coming out at?

Comment: Image displaying in less height than the original image. width is ok. I cannot attach an image here :(